# excel get in one cell all the cells containing specific text

Tags: excel, row

In excel, i would like to see in only one cell a list of all the cells location which contains specific text, is that feasible?

For example: I want to see in only one cell, A7, the location of all cells containing "FALSE" value: A2, B3

[image]

To get the location, i think i can use the formula IF(ISERROR(A1:B4),ROW()) but i get a table as a result instead of all the values in one cell.

Comment: The screenshot is the result you're looking for, right? I believe this would require a VBA based solution. If the range you're interested in is small and will not change, you could use a string of CONCATENATE/IFs, but it would be a very long and ugly formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final formula:

(Replace semicolon with comma for your Excel version)

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(IF($A$1:$B$5=FALSE;ADDRESS(ROW($A$1:$B$5);COLUMN($A$1:$B$5));"")&", ");"$";"");", , ";"")
```

[image]